# npm node for changing screen resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I'm working on a game with electron. It's FPS dropping when running it on full-screen. I need to change the screen resolution programmatically, like my current resolution is `1280x800`, I needed it to be `800x600` or `1024x768` to increase my game's FPS.

Is there any npm-node to do so?

Comment: i don't know much about nodejs, but if it has a foreign function interface it should be easy enough to call [ChangeDisplaySettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183411(v=vs.85).aspx) yourself

Comment: There is [screenres](https://github.com/davidmarkclements/screenres), however, probably not ideal as it lacks cross platform support - its OSX only.

Comment: @RobC Thanks, but I need it for Windows and Linux too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I now the best you can do is to change the canvas width and height attributes to reduce the pixel canvas count and resize it to fit the viewport.

Note that the `canvas` `width` and `height` **attributes** are different from its CSS properties, e.g. `<canvas width=4 height=4 style={width: 100px; height: 100px}>` will result in pixels being upscaled by the factor of 25 (so similar to 4x4 pixel image resized using CSS).